# PHP/Magento - Variables within foreach not being updated properly

Tags: php, magento

I'm having problems with a foreach loop in a magento template:

```
$cats = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories();
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    if($cat->getIsActive()&&$cat->getProductCount()) {
        echo "<div class=\"grid_6\">";
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_new')
            ->setTemplate('catalog/product/new.phtml')
            ->setCategoryId($cat->getId())
            ->setColumnCount(2)
            ->setBlockTitle("Just Added in <a href=".$cat->getUrl().">".$cat->getName()."</a>")
            ->toHtml();
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Results in an identical block being repeated 4 times (I have 4 main categories) when it should show 4 different blocks, one for each category.  It's as if the $cat->getId(), $cat->getName() and $cat->getUrl() statements are not being updated on each new iteration.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks...

Comment: Have you done a dump of $cats to see if the data stored inside is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Hi Jrod - yes I have and it is.  If I echo $cat->getName() I get the right cat name...  It's this getLayout command that is somehow not getting the right data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess here, but it looks like the `catalog/product_new` block wasn't designed to be used multiple times on one request.  If you look at the class definition in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`, its pseudo-constructor includes the following

```
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'    => 86400,
        'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),
    ));
```

The presence of a `cache_lifetime` and `cache_tags` property are hints to Magento's Layout rendering system that this block should be cached.

So, what's happening is the first time you render the block, the results are cached.  The next time you render the block, instead of re-rendering this the results are pulled out of cache.

My advice here would be to create a custom code module, write a new block class that extends the old block class and redefines either `_construct` or `getCacheKeyInfo` in a such a way that you're "allowed" to render the Block multiple times.

Comment: Or he could just add an additional setData('cache_tags', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG . $cat->getId()) call just before toHtml().

Comment: Thank you Alan - I removed the code you showed above from _construct and created a local copy and this resolved the problem I was having, so you hit the nail on the head :)

Comment: @Daniel - where exactly in new.php would I need to add that code?

Comment: @user364934: just between your setBlockTitle and toHtml() calls in the code you posted above.

Comment: @Daniel Sloof - I added the code as suggested but it resulted in an error: Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings in /home/gp/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 1144

Comment: @Daniel Shoof: Will creating a unique **cache tag** solve this?  It's been my understanding the tags identify a bit of cached information for the clearing scripts, but it's the cache key that needs to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the block, you can just disable caching for the block at render time by adding `->setCacheLifetime(NULL)` right before `->toHtml()`. If the containing block is already cached then there is probably no benefit to caching the child blocks anyway.

Comment: Colin, I tried adding    ->setCacheLifetime(NULL) right before     ->toHtml()  and removed my app/code/local/catalog/product/block/new.php but it resulted in the original problem reappearing.